# Get session variable from on of two places and set as one variable

Tags: php, session

I have this at the top of pages that I don't want people accessing unless they're logged in:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['Register'])){
  if(!isset($_SESSION['Login'])){
    header("location:../notLoggedIn.php");
 }
}
$get_id = $_SESSION['Register'];
$get_id = $_SESSION['Login'];
?>
```

This gets a session variable from the code that adds a new user to the database when a new user registers. It also checks if a session has been set from a user logging in rather than registering. Hence one check for register and one for login.

Then, I'm using the session variable as a regular variable so I can access that data on any other pages I might write for the website. So I can have the users id easily available to me.

This works fine when a user registers but not when a user logs in. So, when a user registers the id they are given in the database is available to me to use as it's set in this code that's at the top of every page which puts their id number into the variable $get_id.

The problem is that this variable is already being used but I want it to contain the users id when the user logs in as well. Is there a way to set the variable to check for either of one session variables?

Comment: use array it will help you.

Comment: you can update the session variable to contain almost whatever you want

Comment: If two variables have two different purposes, then give them two different names. You can also try to use functions and classes so not every variable has global scope. PS: The code that would illustrates your problem is missing from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a check:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Register'])){
   $get_id = $_SESSION['Register'];
}else if(isset($_SESSION['Login'])){
   $get_id = $_SESSION['Login'];
}
```

With this, you have the ID of `Register` if this is set, or the ID of `Login` if `Register` is **not** set but `Login` is.
You could also switch the `Register` and `Login`-Parts in the check, if you want to have `Login` if it is set and if you only want to have `Register` if `Login` is not set.

But if you want both IDs saved to the same variable, you'd have to make an array:

```
$get_id = array(
   "Register" => $_SESSION['Register'],
   "Login" => $_SESSION['Login']);
```

Like this you can then access your `Register` by typing `$get_id['Register'];`.

If you don't want named values, you can omit them, like this:

```
$get_id = array($_SESSION['Register'], $_SESSION['Login']);
```

Like this, you can access your `Register` by typing `$get_id[0];` and your `Login` respectively by typing `$get_id[1];`.

But if you want to save both values to one variable (not an array), I'm afraid, that's not possible. The closest you could do is the check mentioned above.

Alternatively you could, if you're desperate enough, format those both SESSION-variables to strings to concat them together to one variable. But believe me, this would be very very painful to manipulate or use this data.

```
$get_id = $_SESSION['Register']. " ".$_SESSION['Login'];
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. That helped a lot. I also figured out that I was looking for $id on one of my pages rather than $get_id. Woops

Comment: Also, the check was the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can update the contents of the session variable at any point really and you can structure the contents to make it more usable - an array or object work well.

```
$svar='usr';

/* you could further test for the session variable having particular properties using `property_exists` */

if( !isset( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ){
    echo "session variable not set ~ redirect non logged in users using `header()` ";
}

/* later you can set the variable after login */
$_SESSION[ $svar ]=new stdClass();

$_SESSION[ $svar ]->username='joe.bloggs';
$_SESSION[ $svar ]->registered=true;


echo '<pre>',print_r( $_SESSION[ $svar ],true ),'</pre>';

$username=$_SESSION[ $svar ]->username;
echo $username;
```